# Python: Removing columns from a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, database, csv

I would like to extract any rows that contain an author.description with the keyword "doctor". I think something like .iloc could work for this, but am unsure how I would select this particular column?
Any help is appreciated

Note: I am using Twitter API V2, If anyone know any hacks for this that avoid opening the file and removing columns let me know, ive attempted the following within the query_param..
**-bio:doctor** and **-bio_contains:doctor** and they do not work

[image]

```
import requests
import expansions
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
import csv
import sys
import time

bearer_token = "bearer token"

search_url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all"

query_params = {'query': 'vaccine -is:retweet -is:verified -baby -lotion -shampoo lang:en has:geo place_country:US',
                'tweet.fields':'created_at,lang,text,geo,author_id,id,public_metrics,referenced_tweets',
                'expansions':'geo.place_id,author_id', 
                'place.fields':'contained_within,country,country_code,full_name,geo,id,name,place_type',
                'user.fields':'description,username,id',
                'start_time':'2021-01-20T00:00:01.000Z',
                'end_time':'2021-02-17T23:30:00.000Z',
                'max_results':'10'}


def create_headers(bearer_token):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}
    return headers


def connect_to_endpoint(url, headers, params):
    response = requests.request("GET", search_url, headers=headers, params=params)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
    return response.json()


def main():
    headers = create_headers(bearer_token)
    json_response = connect_to_endpoint(search_url, headers, query_params)
    json_response = expansions.flatten(json_response) 
    df = pd.json_normalize(json_response['data'])
    df.to_csv("myfile.csv", encoding="utf-8-sig")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should be what you are looking for?

```py
import pandas as pd


my_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'geo.id': ['lkajsdf', 'alksjdf', 'assssddf'], 
     'author.description': ['Hey, I am a doctor', 'I am also a doctor', 'Me? I am a lawyer']})

drop = my_data['author.description'].str.contains('doctor|hospital')
result = my_data[-drop]
result
```

Result

|  | geo.id | author.description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | assssddf | Me? I am a lawyer |

Comment: This looks like it is searching for "doctor" within my data then storing it. Is that correct? Since I am unsure which author.descriptions will be returned in my search I can't specify keywords within them I would want to keep. I can only attempt to remove the ones I dont want such as "doctor" or "hospital", etc.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I think my edit would be what you want then with doctor and hospital being dropped?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use pandas to create a dataframe (df) of normalized json data, you can do something like:

```
authorDescptionContainingDoctor = df[df['author.description'].str.contains('doctor')]
```

This stores every row that's column 'author.description' contains the keyword 'doctor' into it's own df, so it does not modify the original dataset but you can separately filter or further analyze the new df.

For further explanation of what's going on above:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html